# TinyMCE editor content missing after drag and move

Tags: javascript, jquery, drag-and-drop, tinymce

I've got a page with multiple TinyMce editors and i have drag and drop feature enabled which allows me to change the order of each items.

But as i drag-drop an editor its content gets removed.

See the screen shots :

Before Drag-Drop
[image: Before Drag-Drop]

After Drag-Drop
[image: After Drag-Drop]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Finally fixed the issue...

The solution is to first shut down the tinymce instance (id needed!)

`tinymce.execCommand('mceRemoveControl',true,'editor_id');`

then do the DOM action and reinit the tinymce instance

`tinymce.execCommand('mceAddControl',true,'editor_id');`

Comment: can you explain how you implemented this solution?

Comment: For those who are using v5 of TinyMCE : To remove the instance
`tinymce.execCommand('mceRemoveEditor', false, 'editorid');`. To add the instance
`tinymce.execCommand('mceAddEditor', false, 'editorid');`

Answer (score 0):

Add following code on drag end event:

```
onDragEnd(event: any) {
  var tinymceId = 'tinymceId_' + event.source.data.index; //get selected element id
  tinymce.get(tinymceId ).remove(); //remove existing instance
  $('#' + tinymceId ).closest('.mce-tinymce.mce-container').show();
  tinymce.init({id: tinymceId , selector: '#' + tinymceId , height: 200}; //you can add other properties into init()
}
```